# How can I create an initialization block in an pseudo algorithm block in Latex?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic

How can I create the following algorithm block in Latex? I have everything except the init block. How can I create this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}    

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{$D$ = $<u,i,r>$}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{feat, iters, $\lambda$, $\eta$}
\Output{$A$, $B$}
\For{count $\leftarrow 1$ \KwTo iters}{
    $D \leftarrow$ Shuffle($D$) \;
    \For{$<u,i,r> \in D$}{
        $err_{ui} \leftarrow r - A_uB_i^T$ \;
        $A_u \leftarrow A_u + \eta(err_{ui}B_i - \lambda A_u)$ \;
        $B_i \leftarrow B_i + \eta(err_{ui}A_u - \lambda B_i)$ \;
    }
}
\caption{Stochastic Gradient Descent}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Algorithm example]

Is there an online editor/generator for algorithm blocks in Latex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far. Searching this side will give you some hints to start.

Comment: @albert you are right. I have provided a minimal working example. How this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\SetKwProg` to create your own block:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}    
\SetKwProg{Init}{init}{}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{$D$ = $<u,i,r>$}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
\Input{feat, iters, $\lambda$, $\eta$}
\Output{$A$, $B$}
\init{
\For{$u \in Users(D)$}{
    $A_u \leftarrow$ Vector(size: $feat)
}
\For{count $\leftarrow 1$ \KwTo iters}{
    $D \leftarrow$ Shuffle($D$) \;
    \For{$<u,i,r> \in D$}{
        $err_{ui} \leftarrow r - A_uB_i^T$ \;
        $A_u \leftarrow A_u + \eta(err_{ui}B_i - \lambda A_u)$ \;
        $B_i \leftarrow B_i + \eta(err_{ui}A_u - \lambda B_i)$ \;
    }
}
\caption{Stochastic Gradient Descent}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some typos in your solution. Should be:

```
...
\Init{}{
\For{$u \in Users(D)$}{
    $A_u \leftarrow$ Vector(size: $feat$)
}
...
```